# Disable Terminal Scrolling in Python?

Tags: python

Does anyone know how I can disable the terminal scroll?

I've searched the internet, but I have found no solutions yet. I've searched throughout SO but all I've found is posts with no answer or people confused about why they need to disable scrolling. I even searched the Python Docs, but only found the curses module, but it probably can't solve my problem.

I thought I found a solution

There is a bash command called `tput` and if you execute the command with the arg `smcup` then it disables scrolling.

So I tried doing this with a subprocess.

```py
subprocess.run("bash -c tput smcup", shell=True)
```

However, I think it executes the command in a subshell as it doesn't affect the original shell at all.

The second thing I found was the curses module, but I don't really think it can do what I'm looking for.

I looked on the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) for the curses module, but all I found that was scrolling the terminal with the module, but not disabling it.

So is there some kind of module or function I could use to disable the terminal scroll?

Comment: `subprocess.run(['tput', 'smcup'])` -- `tput` isn't a shell builtin, there's no reason to use `shell=True` or `bash -c` here.

Comment: Moreover: `tput` doesn't change your _shell's_ state at all; it queries or updates the _terminal's_ state only. The terminal state isn't specific to any individual shell, so the "executes the command in a subshell" behavior is 100% irrelevant.

Comment: Beyond that, 100% of everything tput does you _can_ do from Python; the thing `tput` buys over writing control sequences to the terminal directly is that it looks up the right control sequences to use for your current `TERM`, but that's something any other terminfo or curses library client can also do.

Comment: Anyhow -- can you show us how you're testing behavior and determining that `tput smcup` doesn't work when run as a subprocess? (Note that `bash -c tput smcup` doesn't work because the quoting's wrong; it would need to be `bash -c 'tput smcup'` or else the `smcup` argument put into the `$0` slot and ignored).

Comment: Great; glad to hear that helped. We have duplicates for that particular mistake in the knowledge base already (and as I said before, it's better to avoid using any shell at all, which _likewise_ moots the issue), so I don't think it makes sense to add an answer here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well I running `tput smcup`, and it worked. But when running it through Python's subprocess module, it didn't work. I just assumed it was creating a subshell because the module is literally called subprocess, plus I'm pretty sure `bash -c` creates a subshell.

Comment: Not all subprocesses are subshells. For that matter, `bash -c` starts a subprocess which is a shell, but that subprocess _isn't_ a subshell; a subshell is what you get when a shell `fork()`s with no `execve()` -- meaning it inherits the parent shell's local variables etc. When the parent is a Python interpreter instead of a shell, what it gets from a `fork()` with no execve() is a sub-Python-interpreter, not a subshell; and what it gets when it does a fork _followed by_ an execve() is just a new shell, not a "subshell".

Comment: If it were otherwise, the only way you could have a shell that _wasn't_ a subshell was when you were using a shell as your init process (PID 1), because that's the only process that isn't a subprocess of anything else.

Comment: Anyhow -- again, `bash -c` is pointless here. `shell=True` adds `sh -c` to your argument list, so when you use _both_ `shell=True` and an explicit `bash -c` you get `sh -c "bash -c tput smcup"` -- sh starting bash starting tput; which is silly because you don't need _either_ `sh` or `bash` in the first place; and when you _do_ use bash (unnecessarily) here without correct quoting, you get the bug of `bash -c program arg1` completely ignoring arg1 because the only thing it was told to execute as a script was the string `program`.